# Job control in Ruby - SIGCONT handlers not working, SIGTSTP handler working only for irb. What am I missing?

Tags: ruby, console, tty, pty

I was working on trying to implement some kind of shell job control for a custom event loop handler with the GLib2 API in Ruby-GNOME. Ideally, this would be able to handle SIGTSTP and SIGCONT signals, to background the process at a TTY when running under a shell and to resume the background process on 'fg' from the shell.

I've not been able to figure out how to completely approach this with the API available in Ruby.

For a simpler usage case, I thought that I'd try adding a similar job support for IRB. I've added the following to my `~/.irbrc`. The SIGTSTP handler seems to work, but the process remains suspended even after SIGCONT from `fg` in BASH.

```
## conditional section for  ~/.irbrc
## can be activated with `IRB_JOBS_TEST=Defined irb`
if ENV['IRB_JOBS_TEST']

  module Jobs
    TSTP_HDLR_ORIG ||= Signal.trap("TSTP") do
      STDERR.puts "\nJobs: backgrounding #{Process.pid} (#{TSTP_HDLR_ORIG.inspect}, #{CONT_HDLR_ORIG.inspect})"
      Process.setpgid(0, Process.ppid)
      TSTP_HDLR_ORIG.call if TSTP_HDLR_ORIG.respond_to?(:call)
    end

    CONT_HDLR_ORIG ||= Signal.trap("CONT") do
      Process.setpgid(0, Process.pid)

      STDERR.puts "Continuing in #{Process.pid}" ## not reached, not shown

      IRB.CurrentContext.thread.wakeup ## no effect

      CONT_HDLR_ORIG.call if CONT_HDLR_ORIG.respond_to?(:call)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm testing this on FreeBSD 13.1. I've read the FreeBSD termios(4), tcsetpgrp(3), and fcntl(2)  manual pages. I'm not sure how much of the terminal-related API is available in Ruby.

The TSTP handler here seems to work, but the CONT handler is apparently not ever reached. I'm not sure if the TSTP handler is actually doing enough for - in effect - backgrounding the process in the shell's process group and relinquishing the controlling terminal.

With that TSTP handler, I can then background the IRB process in the shell with Ctrl-z. I can also foreground the process with 'fg' or BASH '%', but then the process is unresponsive. FreeBSD's `Ctl-t` handler shows the process as suspended. Apparently nothing in my CONT handler is reached.

I'm really stumped about what's failing in this approach - what my TSTP/CONT handlers are missing, what's available in Ruby, and why the process stays suspended after 'fg' in the shell.

In a more complex example, with the code I've written for glib2 it was apparently not enough to just call

```
Process.setpgid(0, Process.ppid)
```

as the process was not being backgrounded then. This would probably need another question though, as the example code for it isn't quite so short. So, I thought I'd try starting with IRB ...

After trying to foreground the process, then with `Ctrl-t` at the TTY on FreeBSD, I'm seeing the following

```
$ %                                                                                                        
IRB_JOBS_TEST=Defined irb                                                                                                           
load: 0.16  cmd: ruby31 4076 [suspended] 2.36r 0.19u 0.03s 1% 23828k             
mi_switch+0xc2 thread_suspend_check+0x260 sleepq_catch_signals+0x113 sleepq_wait_sig+0x9 _cv_wait_sig+0xec tty_wait_background+0x30d ttydev_ioctl+0x14b devfs_ioctl+0xc6 vn_ioctl+0x1a4 devfs_ioctl_f+0x1e kern_ioctl+0x25b sys_ioctl+0xf1 amd64_syscall+0x10c fast_syscall_common+0xf8
```

So, it's blocking in an ioctl on resume?

**Update**

After a few hours of ineffectual hacking about this, I've removed the SIGTSTP and SIGCONT signal handlers from [my GLib example code](https://github.com/rubyblox/pebbl_app/blob/main/sandbox/threads-test.rb) and now it "Just Works". I can background the example app at the console ... at least when it's not running under IRB ... and I can bring it back to the process group foreground with the shell. It resumes running on SIGCONT and everything looks alright in the logging from its main event loop.

I'm still not certain what the missing parts may have been, in may handlers/hacks for SIGTSTP and SIGCONT with IRB. Of course, with the input history recording in IRB it's typically simple enough to just restart the process..

Looking at how other applications have approached job control at the console, I think Emacs wraps its TTY I/O streams in some kind of an encapsulated struct? looking at Emacs' terminal.c mainly.

Glad to see if there's job control available in Ruby though, and it does not even need a custom signal handler for some applications?

Comment: Instead of mucking around with IRB, have you just tried using pry instead?  https://github.com/pry/pry

Comment: Note your update includes a dead link: https://github.com/rubyblox/pebbl_app/blob/main/sandbox/threads-test.rb